# Read a value from spreadsheet X, compare adjacent values between spreadsheets X and Y

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Macro Based Excel file that generates a list of items received and their status (i.e. received, repaired, etc).  This program runs daily, and right now I have it capture the previous day's list and place it in a spreadsheet called PreviousData before updating with the current day's list, which is placed in a spreadsheet called Data; this is used to compare what we believe we fixed/changed status on the previous day.

I'm basically self taught in VBA, so I'm not super efficient or experienced.  What I want to do is the following:

1. On the Data Spreadsheet, grab the order number starting in J2
2. Switch to the PreviousData Spreadsheet, and search for the order number from step 1

Scenario A: If the order number is found on PreviousData, compare the status values next to the order number on both sheets; if they differ, run some code otherwise do nothing

Scenario B: If the order number is not found on PreviousData, do nothing

1. Repeat until 1st blank cell encountered in Data Spreadsheet

I did some searching around the interwebs and found something (it might have been from this forum, actually) that would go row by row and compare cell values, but if scenario B came up the function would fail with "out of range."  Here is the code I tried and have modified to try to get to work:

```
Sub output()

Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim varSheetRMA As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim strRangeRMA As String
Dim Variable As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim Count As Integer

strRangeToCheck = "K2:L1000"
strRangeRMA = "J2:J1000"
' If you know the data will only be in a smaller range, reduce the size of the ranges above.
Debug.Print Now
varSheetA = Worksheets("PreviousData").Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetB = Worksheets("Data").Range(strRangeToCheck) ' or whatever your other sheet is.
varSheetRMA = Worksheets("Data").Range(strRangeRMA)
Debug.Print Now

Sheets("Data").Select
Range("J2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("PreviousData").Select
Cells.Find(What:=Variable, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
        If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
            ' Cells are identical.
            ' Do nothing.
        Else
            ' Cells are different.
            ' Code goes here for whatever it is you want to do.
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow 
End Sub
```

Please help :)

Comment: Also, I started to use the selection code under the defines, but I got stuck with what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should be easier to understand + it does the job.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareStatuses()

 Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
 Dim lr1&, lr2&, i&, j&

 Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
 Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PreviousData")
 lr1 = ws1.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lr2 = ws2.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To lr1
  For j = 2 To lr2
     Set rng1 = ws1.Range("J" & i)
     Set rng2 = ws2.Range("J" & j)
     If StrComp(CStr(rng1.Value), CStr(rng2.Value), vbTextCompare) = 0 And _
        StrComp(CStr(rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value), CStr(rng2.Offset(0, 1).Value) _
         ,vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
         ' found a matching Order + both statuses are different
         ' this is where you wanted to run some code
     End If
     Set rng1 = Nothing
     Set rng2 = Nothing
  Next j
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Nicely done! Though personally I do not like `Dim lr1&, lr2&, i&, j&` LOL

Comment: Just ran it on the data that I have and I ran into a minor snag.  On orders where there are two parts under one order number, it double counted (i.e. instead of saying 2 parts, it reported 4).  I was thinking maybe a temp variable to compare the last value from Data wasn't the same as what it just ran?  I'll try it and report back

Comment: @mehow, one more question for you.  Since orders ship out daily and come off of this report, I want to add a little loop that finds items that shipped (i.e. ones not on the Data spreadsheet) and highlights the row on PreviousData to show it shipped.  I know how to highlight the rows, I tried using the VBA code for "Cells.Find" I can't get it to work; it crashes when I am looking for an item that isn't there (which is basically what I'm trying to do).  Is there a better way?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: its just shorter than typing As Type. You do not have to like it haha

Comment: @Alex: you are running some code to compare the statuses, right? Inside that code/loop apply some conditional formatting to the `ws.Range("J" & j)` that will highlight only the ones where the status has changed.

Comment: @mehow: That makes perfect sense.  I'll give that a shot.  Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: +1, also for me, it's been a long time since I saw the `&`  shorthand for Type declaration!